# Get only domain name from urls using urlsplit

Tags: python, dataset, urllib

I have a dataset with urls in different forms (e.g `https://stackoverflow.com, https://www.stackoverflow.com, stackoverflow.com`) and I need to have only domain name like `stackoverflow`.

I used a `parse.urlsplit(url)` from `urllib` but it's not working well in my case.

How can I get only the domain name?

edit.:

My code :

```
def normalization (df):
  df['after_urlsplit'] = df["httpx"].map(lambda x: parse.urlsplit(x))
  return df

normalization(df_sample)
```

output:

```
            httpx                       after_urlsplit
0   https://stackoverflow.com/       (https, stackoverflow.com, /, , )
1   https://www.stackoverflow.com/   (https, www.stackoverflow.com, /, , )
2   www.stackoverflow.com/           (, , www.stackoverflow.com/, , )
3   stackoverflow.com/               (, , stackoverflow.com/, , )
```

Comment: The `urlsplit` parser follows RFC 1808 which states that if the scheme is not present and the URL does not start with a slash, it is a `rel_path` and has no net_loc. `stackoverflow.com` alone will not be interpreted as a host name but as a relative path. Links in browsers work the same, just the address bar is more error tolerant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New answer, working for urls and host names too

To handle instances where there is no protocol definition (e.g. `example.com`) it is better to use a regex:

```py
import re

urls = ['www.stackoverflow.com',
        'stackoverflow.com',
        'https://stackoverflow.com',
        'https://www.stackoverflow.com/',
        'www.stackoverflow.com',
        'stackoverflow.com',
        'https://subdomain.stackoverflow.com/']

for url in urls:
    host_name = re.search("^(?:.*://)?(.*)$", url).group(1).split('.')[-2]
    print(host_name)
```

This prints `stackoverflow` in all cases.

### Old answer, working for urls only

You can use the value of `netloc` returned by the urlsplit, additionally with some extra tailoring to get the domain (part) you want:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

m = urlsplit('http://subdomain.example.com/some/extra/things')

print(m.netloc.split('.')[-2])
```

This prints `example`.

(However, this would fail on urls like `http://localhost/some/path/to/file.txt`)

Comment: It's not gonna work if i have only `www.` before domain name e.g `www.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: That's true. On the other hand, `www.example.com` is just a path, not an URL. Edited my original answer, added a regex version to deal with both host names / paths and urls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **regular expression(regex)** for this mission.

```
import re

URL = "https://www.test.com"
result = re.search("https?:\/\/(www.)?([\w\.\_]+)", URL)
print(result.group(2))

# output: test.com
```

Comment: It's stil not helping me if in some examples I have only `www` instead of `http://www.`

Insted of regex in this point we can use 
`from urllib import parse
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
parsed_url = parse.urlsplit(url)
parsed_url.netloc` 
and then split by ".", but if I have no _netloc_ part I cant split it

Comment: Why not use regex? You can use this: result.group(1) + result.group(2)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle problems like this is with [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).